Word/term for entertainment but of the sad kind that you'd want to watch on a memorial day?
On sad occasions people want to consume sad movies/songs/documentaries - calling it entertainment sounds wrong but is there a proper term for this kind of content?

What sad occasions? The death of one's dog? I mean...

I'd call it "appropriate/tasteful entertainment" or "somber music/viewing/etc" or something similarly vague. After major events like 9/11 in the USA and after the death of the Queen in the UK there were efforts to provide appropriate listening and viewing. Although there was also the sense that it was inappropriate to watch too much, with Laura Bush a prominent voice that children shouldn't be stuck in front of a TV showing repeated images of death. So the notion of what's suitable isn't simple, and watching sad movies might not be what was required.

commemorative media

I don't think the "entertainment" should be particularly sad for most people; perhaps it should be "subdued entertainment". Something that doesn't contrast too much with current feelings. Sad or neutral, but not hilarious.

tearjerker, from the Movies & TV site

I don't think that people choose sad occasions to "consume entertainment" that has to do with sad things or connotes sad things; instead, they are not averse to such experiences and they are receptive to the message of such cultural communications according to the mood, or rather desire of the moment; sad music is being listen to by a lot of people who are not sad when they do that, but instead who have internalized as years went by the "culture of sadness" and appreciate how the particular work of art they are listening to evokes the feelings they are familiar with.
This is true for literature (poetry), music, films, and other sorts of art. That is not to say that  programming of such cultural material is not associated with memorial days; this seems to be true in fact but it is not exactly the result of an aspiration of the individual, it is rather a tradition that the media perpetuate (true in particular for films). I think, moreover, that normal people never try to alleviate their personal sadness or to indulge in it by immersing themselves in works of art impregnated with sadness; they would naturally tend to abhor this idea as it entails an interference with their feelings.  This being said, I think you still have to call it entertainement, but of a sort that does not belongs to so-called light entertainment, a culturally more potent sort.  I propose a term (that has nothing very innovative) which can be applied generally; everyone has had a taste of it in terms such as "serious literature" and "serious music".
This can be called "serious entertainment" so as to dissociate the term "entertainment" from some of its connotations with merrymaking.  It must be understood that this term encompasses a much greater variety of works of art  than those apt to confer sadness.


Watching a Shakespeare play on television is serious entertainment but not necessarily sad at all.

@Lambie Are you understating that my answer says differently?

Sentimental

a
: marked or governed by feeling, sensibility, or emotional idealism
b
: resulting from feeling rather than reason or thought
a sentimental attachment
a sentimental favorite

Sentimental
Ngram for sentimental usage


Would you say then "sentimental entertainment"?

I think you can, here is an ngram showing that: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sentimental+entertainment&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3. (You can use it in your answer if you like.)

"sentimental" can have a pejorative sense (meaning excessively emotional or trite), although the OP hasn't made it clear what sense they want, so maybe it's OK.

@StuartF the only time I have heard it in that context is when "sentimental" is qualified like "overly sentimental". Do you have any examples of that usage?
